# How to set the runtime Identifiers for win-x64 only

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build

Using VS Community 2022, how to build a project only for win-64 target ?

VS keeps creating multiple runtimes directory (linux, osx, etc) every time i build.

I tried to add a  `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` in the vbproj file but i get an error: "The"HasTrailingSlash" function only accepts a scalar value...".

Here is my vbproj file (first lines):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyProjectName</RootNamespace>
    <StartupObject>MyProjectName.frmStart</StartupObject>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <MyType>WindowsForms</MyType>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
  <ApplicationIcon>Resources\images\my_icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath></OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add these two lines.

```
<SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```